Django login invalid credentials
error Invalid credentials shown when i log in, even username and password is correct
here is my code
views.py
class LogInView(FormView):
    template_name='log_in.html'
    form_class=LogInForm
    success_url=reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        uname=form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        pword=form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        usr = authenticate(username=uname,password=pword)
        if usr is not None and hasattr(usr,'customer') and usr.customer:
            login(self.request,usr)
        else:
            return render(self.request,self.template_name,{'form':self.form_class,'error':'Invalid credentials'})
        return super().form_valid(form)

forms.py
class LogInForm(forms.Form):
    username=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

log_in.html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="d-block">{{form.as_p}}</div>
    <br />
    {% if error %}
    <li style="color: red">{{error}}</li>
    {% endif %}
    <button class="btn border-3 border-primary-subtle text-light">
        Log In
    </button>
</form>

i tried but cant find out what's wrong

If your IF statement is false, you need to find out where it is failing. Try using print(hasAttr(user, 'customer') and print(usr.customer) to see what their values are.
